# Solve for x : $\left(\sin x\right)^{\tan x}=\left(\cos x\right)^{\cot x}$

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, monotone-functions

Solve for x:
$$\left(\sin x\right)^{\tan x}=\left(\cos x\right)^{\cot x}$$

**My Attempt:**

One obvious solution is obtained by writing the given equation as

$$\left(\sin x\right)^{\tan x}=\left(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}- x)\right)^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}- x)}$$

Clearly,$x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$ are possible solutions.

So the general solution can be written as

$x=\frac{\pi}{4}\pm n\pi$.

But how can I rule out the other solutions or there really aren't other solutions.

Also,if I let $f(x)=\left(\sin x\right)^{\tan x}$,then given equation is equivalent to

$f(x)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$

i.e. $f(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=f(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)$

Can this lead to some conclusion

Comment: Are you allowed to take logarithms? Doing so along with rewriting the entire equation in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$ reduces it to $\sin^2(x)\ln(\sin(x))=\cos^2(x)\ln(\cos(x))$ which leads to $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ (and thus the solutions you found).

Comment: The given equation is equivalent to $(\sin x\cos x)^{\sin x} = (\sin x\cos x)^{\cos x}$.

Comment: $$ S\equiv \sin x$$ and $$C=\cos x = \pm \sqrt{1-S^2}$$ mean
$$ S^{S/C} =C^{C/S}$$
Take this to the power $SC$
$$ S^{S^2} =C^{C^2}$$, so apparently $S=C$ is enforced